# unfortunately, *appname* has stopped with MonoGame

Tags: android, xamarin, monogame

I just downloaded MonoGame and created a MonoGame Android project in Visual Studio. When I run it, it starts an Android emulator, but the screen remains black. `graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Green);` doesn't work and it doesn't render any textures.

Edit: It was black because emulator wasn't completely started yet. I have to press run, wait few minutes(rly long) until emulator starts and then press run again, then it shows monogame logo but after that it show message: unfortunately, *appname* has stopped.
I downloaded WrokingDroid example from official page and it also shows the same message, which means I can't run any app, it just crashes.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the draw method to make sure it's actually being called?

Comment: Yep that makes sense. The emulators are typically really slow unfortunately. Normally I would say rather than editing your question with the solution, you should write your own answer and ask a new one, although I suspect you don't have enough rep for that.

Comment: Well, you are right, I just registered yesterday. Any ideas why it crashes?

Comment: Just why it doesn't work, I didn't do anything wrong. I was so happy that I can code with xna for android. This Monogame...is it really working for someone?

Comment: MonoGame definitely works on Android. Most likely the problems you're experiencing are more to do with the emulator. I've never really used the emulator enough to know much about it but I have run MonoGame on a real Android device before.